# How can I use sort expression to dynamically sort on object attribute?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects and I'd like to dynamically sort the list based on a parameter.
Here is an example that show's what works and what doensn't work when I try to use parameter.

```
const field = 'email'
const users = [{Array of users}]
users = users.sort((a, b) => (a.email > b.email? 1 : -1)); << WORKS
users = users.sort((a, b) => (a.['email'] > b['email']? 1 : -1));  << WORKS

users = users.sort((a, b) => (a.[`'${field}'`] > b[`'${field}'`]? 1 : -1));  << DOESN'T WORK
```

How can I dynamically sort the list based on a defined parameter?

Comment: Just a[field] or b[field] given it’s a string

Comment: Side note; assuming that an email variable is a string, you should be using `a.email.localeCompare(b.email)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually pass variables directly into the square bracket notation:

```
users = users.sort((a, b) => a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1);
```

I don't recommend this, but if you did want to use template strings it would look more like this:

```
a[`${field}`]
```

If you are sorting by string fields, you'd be better off using [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) for your comparison:

```
users = users.sort((a, b) => { 
  return a[field].toLowerCase().localeCompare(b[field].toLowerCase());
});
```

I also wanted to point out that for a numeric sort, it's more common to subtract the numbers than to compare them (this is descending order, switch the order to `a[field] - b[field]` for ascending):

```
users = users.sort((a, b) => b[field] - a[field]);
```

---

A few additional helper functions based on the discussion in the comments:

```
function stringSort(a, b) {
  return a[field].toLowerCase().localeCompare(b[field].toLowerCase());
}

function numberSort(a, b) {
  return b[field] - a[field];
}

users = users.sort(field === 'email' ? stringSort : numberSort);
```

Comment: This works, thx! Now, the last step is i want to lowercase the string so it sorts on lowercase values. I tried this
users = users.sort((a, b) => a[field].toLowerCase() > b[field].toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1); but it doesn't like it. How to?

Comment: Added another example using `localeCompare`, which is the preferred method for sorting strings.

Comment: I get error of a[field].toLowerCase is not a function . FYI, i am setting field this way when using real exampe. const field = payload.sortfield  where payload is object and sortfield is just a string of say "email". Not sure if that makes a difference on why this isn't working.

Comment: Yes, `localeCompare` will only work if your fields are strings. You may need to add some logic to use the `a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1` numeric fields, and use `localeCompare` for string fields.

Comment: I added a basic example of how you can accomplish this. Note that `field` has to be defined in the same scope as your `field` variable, otherwise `field` inside the sort function will be undefined.

Comment: yea, that was it..the initial sort field was numeric, which was causing the error. Just needed to account for numbers, strings and dates

Answer (score 0):

this `'` is extra in last statement,

```
users = users.sort((a, b) => (a.[`${field}`] > b[`${field}`]? 1 : -1));
```

btw the result of above is the same this one (for demonstration purpose only

```
users = users.sort((a, b) => a[field.toString()] > b[field.toString()] ? 1 : -1);
```

so the best way is the one that @wex has already suggested which is to directly put the variable in brackets:

```
users = users.sort((a, b) => a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1);
```